# jQuery .hover effect doesn't work on "li" but works on "a"

Tags: jquery

I have the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/vFJvL/ 
when you mouseover Submenu3 the product list dropsdown but, when you mouseover each product it hides them again..
I tried adding .hvr class into li element: http://jsfiddle.net/vFJvL/2/ it didn't work

I would like each product to be displayed as long as you mouseover the outer li..

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Can we also stop it toggling multiple times when mouse over a couple of times in a short time (like 1 sec).. I guess we need to use stop() somewhere else

Comment: Since you're pretty new here, I might suggest picking a non-generic user name that we might recognize next time we cross paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/vFJvL/5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Hide the tooglebox when page load
    $(".sub").hide(); 
    //slide up and down when hover over heading 2
    $(".hvr").hover(function(){
        // slide toggle effect set to slow you can set it to fast too.
        $(".sub", this).slideToggle(); 
               //<-- get the element with class `sub` inside this li and show it
        return true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, can you also explain it?

Comment: @user718369 -- i added an explanation ^_^

Comment: Beat me to it! and with better syntax, too.

Comment: Nice answer, really like the syntax.
What is the difference with or without return true?;

Comment: EDIT: Can we also stop toggling multiple times when mouse over a couple of times in a short time (like 1 sec).. I guess we need to use stop() somewhere else

Comment: @Neal oh, okey :) thought it was some jquery guru magic going on.

Answer (score 0):

It is the `next()` method giving you the problem. Try using `find()`

JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/vFJvL/6/

**HTML**

```
<li class="hvr"><a href="#"> Submenu3 </a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sub").hide(); 
    $(".hvr").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".sub").slideToggle();
        return true;
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer is essentially the long-form of Neal's answer.